# Help with identifying story about a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, horror, werewolf

When I was in middle school, I read a book in the library about a girl and her classmates going camping. There, it turns out that one of her classmates is a werewolf and she ends up biting the protagonist, turning her into a werewolf as well. The protagonist then struggles living a normal life for a bit before confronting the classmate who bit her. The book takes place somewhere in the 70's or 80's. I cannot for the life of me remember the name of this book and I've been searching for years.